# Text decoration in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: ruby, email, outlook, vt100, ansi-colors

I am sending a file via mutt to an e-mail address. I would like to make certain text appear bold in the e-mail in Outlook. I was hoping it is possible through the base set of ruby commands.

I tried using `\e` commands, and that works well from a Terminal Window, but the output file just literally shows the `\e` commands (like `\e[0m`). I think this is because a Terminal Window is an ASCII interpreter and Outlook is not.

Answer (score 0):

use the HTML tag `<strong>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby on Rails' [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). Use its `html` method and do the text decoration in HTML.